# Multiple pages on a single page

Tags: pages

I have the following code (created very kindly by alchemyth in response to a question I posted on the WordPress.org forum [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/display-multiple-pages-on-one-page?replies=6#post-5534924)) that I hope to use to display lots of pages on a single page:

```
<?php
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'page',
  'post__in' => array( 2, 5, 35, 67 ) //list of page_ids
);
$page_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $page_query->have_posts() ) :
echo '<div class="pages-on-page">';
//print any general title or any header here//
while( $page_query->have_posts() ) : $page_query->the_post();
echo '<div class="page-on-page" id="page_id-' . $post->ID . '">';
//print any output you want per page//
echo '</div>';
endwhile;
echo '</div>';
else:
//optional text here is no pages found//
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

As a newby though, I am unsure where to put it to make it work! I would be very grateful if someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Wordpress Page Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates);

You can create a file with structure to match your current theme and place your code in the content area ( or place an action hook for your special content ).

Example for Twenty Twelve:

```
/*
Template Name: My Custom Page
*/

get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="site-content">
    <div id="content" role="main">

        <?php
        $args = array(
          'post_type' => 'page',
          'post__in' => array( 2, 5, 35, 67 ) //list of page_ids
        );
        $page_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        if( $page_query->have_posts() ) :
        echo '<div class="pages-on-page">';
        //print any general title or any header here//
        while( $page_query->have_posts() ) : $page_query->the_post();
        echo '<div class="page-on-page" id="page_id-' . $post->ID . '">';
        //print any output you want per page//
        echo '</div>';
        endwhile;
        echo '</div>';
        else:
        //optional text here is no pages found//
        endif;
        wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>

    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

****Do not forget to start the file with < ? php

Save this code as a PHP file with almost any name `your_custom_template.php` and place it into your child theme folder.  Then add a new page and assign the page template as `My Custom Page` as seen above in the code.

That should get you at least started enough to see your code on the front of the website.

Comment: I have put the code into a page using a php plugin using 'default template' and 'no parent' - not working though - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would first need to know what plugin you are talking about.  But before that, have you looked at the Wordpress Codex link I gave in my answer?

Comment: The plugin is [here](http://www.willmaster.com/software/WPplugins/insert-php-wordpress-plugin.php). And yes, I did look, but I must confess an awful lot of it goes over my head - I will persevere!

Comment: What is the theme you are using?  I may be able to get you started with an example template.

Comment: I am using twentytwelve - have created a child theme though, as have modified it a bit already.

Comment: Would it be helpful to post my url?

Comment: Thank you very much - however, I have no option to create a custom page in the edit page mode. - Only "default template", "front page template", "full page template" and "up".

Comment: Do you have FTP access to your site?  You can drag and drop a file into the folder

Comment: Yes - the file is now in child folder. How do I call it?

Comment: Just refresh where you edit a page in the Wordpress admin area.  It should now be in the page template dropdown

Comment: No joy I am afraid - sorry this must be really frustrating for you - I am clearly missing something very obvious!

Comment: I just copy the above code and add < ? php at start, is that right?

Comment: I have tried adding it into public_html folder (root folder) & calling it directly in address bar - just white page :(

Comment: I have to +1 for your help - sorry I couldn't make it work! :/

Comment: You need to add the code for the output  //print any output you want per page//

Comment: @ Brad Dalton - many thanks - breakthrough at last!!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me with WP Twenty Twelve, don't forget to change page IDs

```
 <?php
/*
Template Name: My Custom Page
*/

get_header();
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => get_option('posts_per_page'), // значение по умолчанию берётся из настроек, но вы можете использовать и собственное
    'paged'          => $current_page // текущая страница
    );
    query_posts(
    array( 'post_type'=>'page', 'post__in' => array( 6891, 9400 ) ) //change page IDs
); ?>

<div id="primary" class="site-content">
    <div id="content" role="main">
<?php
            while ( have_posts() ) :
                the_post();
                ?>
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
                    <div class="entry-page-image">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                    </div><!-- .entry-page-image -->
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>

                <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

    </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your contribution and welcome to WordPress.StackExchange! Some things to consider for a possible [edit] to your answer, that might drive more upvotes to it and therefore unlocking more possibilities for you on this site: Please keep in mind that not everyone can read Cyrillic characters. It also helps to explain _why_ your code snippet will help the OP solve their problem. I hope that helps! Have a nice day!