# Multiple posts/pages in one page?

Tags: query-posts, get-posts, homepage

I'm trying to create website with index page which will have 2+ different boxs with different content generated from post or pages in WP administration. This page will be looks like this wireframe. I'm using the `TwentyFourteen` template and I edit `index.php` in templates folder.

**What I tried**: [Multiple pages on one with different HTML](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/100221/multiple-pages-on-one-with-different-html) and [Multiple pages on a single page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/143352/multiple-pages-on-a-single-page). But this isn't working properly for me. These instructions do not insert into 4 different divs.

**What I want:** I want into 2, or more, different `divs` on the index page of my website include 2, or more, posts/pages from WP administration into this different `divs`. I can this problem solved by using `<?php include("content-of-div.php) ?>`, but this can't be edited in WP admin.

[image]

Comment: you mean you want to have 4 boxes each with a category archieve?

Comment: What does *not working properly* means. Explain in an [edit]

Comment: @maioman I don't know you mean with "archieve" ? I want 4 box (or more) into which I can link to it content (post or page) by ID.

Comment: @PieterGoosen These instructions do not insert into 4 different `divs`.

Comment: I suggest to look into [page templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) to achieve what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**More complex way**

I use it this way (I'm usually doing one page design, however the method of loading pages is still same).

Fo Theme options, I'm using [Option tree plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/option-tree/) where my clients could just checkbox which pages should appear there (it's passed by it's ID) and than I load it into the script.

```
<?php
// loading pages which should appear by option tree setting, but you can add your IDs of pages manually there
$ids = ot_get_option( 'show_pages', false);
//if nothing is set
if ($ids == false )
{$ids = array('9999');}

//post_type page, ordered
$page_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'page', 'orderby' => array('menu_order' => 'ASC'),  'post__in' => array_values($ids)) );

if ( $page_query-> have_posts() ) : while ($page_query-> have_posts() ) : $page_query-> the_post(); 

$template_file = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_wp_page_template', TRUE );
        //page template (name of your template)
        if ($template_file=='page-contactform.php') {
           //here you should include it 
           include 'page-contactform.php'; 
        }
        elseif ($template_file=='page-vyrobky.php') { 
           include 'page-vyrobky.php'; 
        }
        else {
            include 'page.php'; 
        }
         endwhile; else : ?>
    <p>Nothing found</p>

<?php endif; 
      wp_reset_postdata();
 ?>
```

**Or REALLY SIMPLE WAY:**

```
   <?php
    $include = get_pages('include=11'); //here go your ID number
    $content = apply_filters('the_content',$include[0]->post_content);
    echo $content;
    ?>
```

Comment: Never ever use `query_posts` unless your intention is to break your page's functionalities :-)

Comment: @kybernaut.cz Thanks for your answer, but this is too complicated for me. Is there a simple solution as php `include()` but only according to include by ID from WP?

Comment: @PieterGoosen I've thought that for main query its ok, nope?  But I've changed it to `page_query` (hopefully I haven't skipped something somewhere)

Comment: I think you mean `WP_Query` :-) That is the correct way to create a custom query

Comment: @Mardzin I've edited my post, _the really simple way_ should work for you, just put the correct page number there.

Comment: @kybernaut.cz Yes, I just trying this ulow solution what I exactly need.

Comment: @kybernaut.cz I have an error - `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/index.php on line 24`

Comment: And do you have added correct ID of page? For me it's working fine.

Comment: @kybernaut.cz Oh, sorry :) It works fine! Thank you so much! Díky :)